# How to copy specific cell in the same row if target cell is not blank

Tags: vba, excel

How can I do to make this work?

Workbook named "1":
 For range B2:R90，
 if B2 is not blank, then copy C2,E2,G2,L2 & M2,
 automatically open workbook named "2",
 and paste to B2,
 if B3 is not blank, then copy C3,E3,G3,L3 & M3, paste to B3 of workbook "2", and go on.
 When finished, close and save Workbook "2", but leave workbook "1", opened.

I only know to write code using below method, but I am sure this cannot worked... ><

```
For Each cell In Sheets("01OCT")
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("B5:R90").Value) Then
       Copy
       Else
       Nothing
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/close-open.html   (open and close workbook)

Comment: So you want to overwrite the contents of workbook "2" cell "B2" each time a line is not blank?

Comment: No, I don't want to overwrite everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant to increment the cell in which you are pasting values (B2, B3 ...) and not override B2 every time, and assuming you don't need anything except the cell contents, the following should work for you:

```
Sub copyCells()
    Dim mainWb As Workbook, mainWs As Worksheet
    Dim someWb As Workbook

    Set mainWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set mainWs = mainWb.Worksheets("01OCT")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Workbooks.Open fileName:="C:\path\2.xlsx", ReadOnly:=False
    Set someWb = Workbooks("2.xlsx")
    mainWs.Activate

    For i = 2 To mainWs.Range("B5:R90").Rows.count
        If Not IsEmpty(Range("B" & i).Value) Then
            someWb.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value = mainWs.Range("C" & i).Value
            someWb.Worksheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value = mainWs.Range("E" & i).Value
            someWb.Worksheets(1).Range("D" & i).Value = mainWs.Range("G" & i).Value
            someWb.Worksheets(1).Range("E" & i).Value = mainWs.Range("L" & i).Value
            someWb.Worksheets(1).Range("F" & i).Value = mainWs.Range("M" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i

    Workbooks("2.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the point of setting `ScreenUpdating = True` **before** the loop? Then the user has to see the massive amount of screen flickering that will occur, as well as the fact the code will be slower.

Comment: This code is more like function "concatenate ",but what I need is content in    separate cell, not all content in one cell. But still thank you very much for your help and passion, maybe I can use this code in other time!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: my mistake, I went a bit back and forth when writing it. I will fix it shortly.

Comment: @TonyY: I'm sorry, your description of the problem made it seem like a concatenate problem. I'll rewrite, it's easy enough.

Comment: @vsoraas : Thank you very much!!! This works perfectly! I really appreciate with your help, I've learned a lot of new things. Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

Change Folder names & Workbook names & sheet names to suite

```
Sub GetDataTo2()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long

    Dim bk As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rws As Long

    Set wb = Workbooks("1.xlsm")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    With ws
        r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Columns("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"

        Set bk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Dave\Downloads\2.xlsx")
        Set sh = bk.Sheets("Sheet1")

        With sh
            rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ws.Range("C2:C" & r & ",E2:E" & r & ",G2:G" & r & ",L2:M" & r).Copy
            .Range("A" & rws).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With

        bk.Save
        bk.Close True
        .AutoFilterMode = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Great idea to user `AutoFilter` instead of a loop!. Two issues though: 1)you don't turn `ScreenUpdating` back on. 2) the line `ws.Range("C2 ...` needs to have `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` between the `)` and the `.Copy` or else, it will copy every cell, not just the filtered ones.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman 1. you don't have to turn ScreenUpdating back on. 2. Only the visible cells will be copied.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I also thought you have to turn it back on, but now I set that it is not necessary (perhaps this changed in newer XL versions). Although I know when you copy / paste filtered cells manually it only picks up what is filtered, I feel like I ran into trouble with this method when coding before. Good to know I can save some keystrokes!

Comment: Works greatly ! What should I add if I only want to paste only the values, not including borders or any formatting ?